# How do I add instance variables to Devise email templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I am trying to edit the confirmation_instructions.html.erb file to address the new user by first name instead of email.

Current the beginning of the file reads...

Hi, <%= @email %>,

How do I add an instance variable @first_name to the controller/mailer?

I ran rails generate devise:controllers users, but I just don't see any .rb files where I could add instance variables to confirmation mailer (if there is one)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy, you can just create a Mailer for this:

```
class ConfirmationsMailer < Devise::Mailer
  default from: '<no-reply@example.com>'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
   @token = token
   #you can add your instance variables here
   devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
  end
end
```

And then just tell Devise to use this class:

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
...
config.mailer = 'ConfirmationsMailer'
...
end
```

Restart your server, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to get an attribute from the user model?  For instance the following isnt working  @first_name = current_user.first_name

Comment: Instead of using `current_user`, you can just use the `record` argument from the method, so in your case @first_name = record.first_name

Comment: i came here to say that I figured it out with @first_name = record.first_name  and then saw your post.  thanks for your help

Comment: where would I find what is available in the opts={}

Comment: You can find it in here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/66db52ce31b5d8629f5813a1d7f03a8bc17e5d52/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb but is basically the headers for the email, for example subject, from, to, etc

Comment: thanks.  I also noticed you can change the subject in the devise lcoal file

Comment: You are welcome! If you found the answer useful show me some love by accept it :) thanks

Comment: I would but I do not have enough reputation points.  can you upvote the question?